# Obtener vistas como objetos con jquery en cakephp

Tags: jquery, cakephp, div

Tengo los siguientes divs:

```
<div id="divNeeds" class="row" >
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1 id="h1NeedsTitle" class="lang" key="h1NeedsTitle">Descubrir necesidades</h1>
            <h4 class="lang" key="h4FNeedsFirstText">
                El comienzo de una estratégia funcional es conoces nuestro <br>
                objetivo y que necesidades queremos resolver, de esta forma <br>
                nuestro equipo a través de un laboratorio enlaza un vínculo con <br>
                la marca y da comienzo al plan estrategico.
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" >
            <?php
            echo $this->Form->create('Need', array('class' => '', 'id' => 'msform'));
            ?>
            <label class="lang" key="h1NeedForm">Aprovechemos el tiempo y comencemos</label>
            <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('client', array('label' => array('text' => "¿Para que marca vamos a trabahar?",
                    'key' => 'lblClient', 'class' => 'lang'), 'placeholder' => 'Dinos el nombre de tu empresa',
                'class' => 'validador txtClient lang', 'key' => 'txtClient'));
            echo $this->Form->input('need', array('label' => array('text' => "Escríbenos acerca de tu necesidad",
                    'key' => 'lblNeed', 'class' => 'lang'), 'placeholder' => 'Agradecemos nos detalles muy bien la necesidad, '
                . 'es nuestro punto de partida para generar ideas quer fortalezcan la estrategia para resolverla.',
                'rows' => '4', 'class' => 'validador txtNeed lang', 'key' => 'txtNeed', 'style' => 'resize: none;'));
            echo $this->Form->input('objective', array('label' => array('text' => "¿Cuál es el objetivo?",
                    'key' => 'lblObjective', 'class' => 'lang'), 'placeholder' => 'Que se quiere alcanzar con la'
                . 'solución de la necesidad, ¿Adquirir usuario? ¿Mejorar ventas? ¿Posicionar la marca? ... entre otros.'
                . ' Agradecemos nos detalles muy bien el objetivo.', 'rows' => '4',
                'class' => 'validador txtObjective lang', 'key' => 'txtObjective', 'style' => 'resize: none;'));
            ?>
            <?php
            $options = array(
                'class' => 'lang',
                'label' => 'Enviar y continuar',
                'key' => 'btnFormNeed'
            );
            echo $this->Form->end($options);
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>


<div id="divHome" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1 id="h1HomeTitle" class="lang" key="h1HomeTitle">Laboratorio estrategico</h1>
            <h4 class="lang" key="h4FHomeFirstText">
                Diseñamos a través de las necesidades de <br> marca la mejor ruta 
                para cumplir con sus <br> objetivos y alcanzar resultados.
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?php
            echo $this->Html->image('Procesos.png', array('alt' => 'Proceso', 'key' => 'imgProcess',
                'class' => 'lang', "width" => "650", "height" => "650"));
            ?>
        </div>

    </div>
```

La idea es que eventualmente tenga varios div no solo esos dos, pero en la vista solo se van a ver los que esten dentro de:

```
<div class="principal visible"></div>
<div class="secundario oculto"></div>
```

Por lo cual con jquery siempre estoy cambiando la info de esos divs, con html();

Así:

```
var htmlDivSecundary = "<div id='div"+id+"' class='row' >"+$("#div"+id).html()+"</div>";
//                alert(htmlDivSecundary);
                $(".oculto").html(htmlDivSecundary);
```

En ese lleno el div con clase oculto con la info del div que esta oculto y lo mismo voy a hacer con el div que contiene la clase visible

La cosa es que quiero crear un archivo cpt para cada div, mi pregunta es desde jquery como cargo el cpt como un objeto desde jquery para meterlo al div con .html(objeto);

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes lograr lo que deseas utilizando los [Elements](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#elements) de CakePHP.

Mi ejemplo se basa principalmente en la versión 3.x pero trataré de especificar para ambas versiones.
Puedes crearlos en `src/Template/Element` para la versión 3.x o en `app/View/Elements` para la 2.x

Agregas los elementos que necesites, por ejemplo: step_1.ctp, step_2.ctp, step_3.ctp, step_4.ctp.

En cada uno de ellos pones el código que desees presentar

**step_1.ctp** (Ejemplo ilustrativo)

```
<div class="step-1">
    <h1>Paso 1</h1>
    <p>
        En gr abordar de pedirle dominio palabra le poetico. Para tono ya ma pais peor otro. Pedazos tuviera yo ah audacia piernas. Marcar saludo sea mismos apenas dio doy nos. Etc por extremos obligaba creencia solteras cuidarla han declarar rio. Conquistas alambicado decoracion la ni implacable el. Reyes morir eso monte mal. Forma susto ex te nuevo el cogio en. 
    </p>
</div>
```

Ya que vamos a llamar los elementos con la funcion [`load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) de jQuery no necesitamos todo lo que llama a `default.ctp` por lo tanto podemos decirle a CakePHP que no llame a ningún layout.

En este caso lo hare en `PagesController.php` recibiendo como parámetro el paso que deseo llamar y seteandolo en una variable para poder utilizarlo en la vista

**PagesController.php**

```
class PagesController extends AppController
{
    // Resto del código

    public function steps($step) {
        // 2.x
        $this->layout = false;
        // 3.x
        $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout(false);

        $this->set('step', 'step_' . $step);
    }
}
```

Y en nuestra vista llamamos al elemento que deseamos

**pages.ctp**

```
<?= $this->element($step) ?>
```

Ya en donde desees llamarlos puedes hacerlo con la función [`load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) antes mencionada.

Prepare este ejemplo que llama a una URL en la nube que utiliza exactamente el mismo código descrito anteriormente

```js
// Función que llamará los distintos elementos
function handleClick(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.step').load(this.href);
}

// Aplicamos un listener a todos los botones que llamarán al elemento
$('body').on('click', '.steps', handleClick);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col text-center">
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
        <a href="https://kacos.pro/pasos/1" class="steps btn btn-primary text-white">Paso 1</a>
        <a href="https://kacos.pro/pasos/2" class="steps btn btn-primary text-white">Paso 2</a>
        <a href="https://kacos.pro/pasos/3" class="steps btn btn-primary text-white">Paso 3</a>
        <a href="https://kacos.pro/pasos/4" class="steps btn btn-primary text-white">Paso 4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col step"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```